# I'm having trouble cleaning up this Bad code script. I found a few errors already but I'm currently stuck on this part

Tags: python, arrays

I need to correct this script on a bad code. There is 5 total errors. Here's what I've corrected so far. I'm stuck at defining an array in line 3. I've gone through and tried to correct this line by line but have had no luck. Would greatly appreciate a push in the right direction to get this code fixed.

```
from array import array

students=array()

def getString(prompt, field):
    valid=False
    while valid==False:
        myString=input(prompt)
        if (len(myString)>0):
            valid=True
        else:
            print("The student's " + field + " cannot be empty. Please try again.")
    return myString

def getFloat(promp, field):
    while True:
        try:
            fNum=float(getString(prompt, field))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a valid number for " + field + ", please try again")
    return fNum

def addStudent():
    first=getString("Enter the student's first name: ", "first name")
    last=getString("Enter the student's last name: ", "last name")
    major=getString("Enter the student's major: ", "major")
    gpa=getFloat("Enter the student's GPA: ", "GPA")
    students.append({"first":first,"last":last,"major":major,"gpa":gpa})

def displayStudents():
    print("\nCollege Roster:")
    print("*************************************************************************")
    if (len(students)==0):
        print("There are no students to display.")
    else:
        print("First Name".ljust(20," ")+"Last Name".ljust(30," ")+"Major".ljust(15," ")+"GPA".ljust(6," "))
        for i in range(len(students)):
            print(students[i]['first'].ljust(20, " "), end="")
            print(students[i]['last'].ljust(30, " "), end="")
            print(students[i]['major'].ljust(15, " "), end="")
            print(str(students[i]['gpa']).ljust(6, " "))
    print("*************************************************************************")

def Main():
    keepGoing=true
    menu="""
*************************************************************************
College Roster System
*************************************************************************
Main Menu:
a) Enter a new Student
b) View all Students
c) Clear Students List
d) Exit
*************************************************************************
Choose an option: """
    while keepGoing:
        choice=input(menu)
        if choice!="":
            if choice.lower()=="a":
                addStudent()
            elif choice.lower()=="b":
                displayStudents()
            elif choice.lower()=="c":
                students.clear()
                print("\nThe list of students is cleared.")
            elif choice.lower()=="d":
                keepGoing=False
            else:
                print("\nThat is not a valid selection. Please try again.\n")
        else:
            print("\nYour selection cannot be empty. Please try again.\n")
    print("\nOkay, goodbye!!!")

if __name__=="__BC02.py__":
    main()
```

I'm stuck trying to define the array. I know there is also additional errors, but I can't get pass this part.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of your code that compiles and seems to run correctly:

```
students=[]

def getString(prompt, field):
    valid=False
    while valid==False:
        myString=input(prompt)
        if (len(myString)>0):
            valid=True
        else:
            print("The student's " + field + " cannot be empty. Please try again.")
    return myString

def getFloat(prompt, field):
    while True:
        try:
            fNum=float(getString(prompt, field))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a valid number for " + field + ", please try again")
    return fNum

def addStudent():
    first=getString("Enter the student's first name: ", "first name")
    last=getString("Enter the student's last name: ", "last name")
    major=getString("Enter the student's major: ", "major")
    gpa=getFloat("Enter the student's GPA: ", "GPA")
    students.append({"first":first,"last":last,"major":major,"gpa":gpa})

def displayStudents():
    print("\nCollege Roster:")
    print("*************************************************************************")
    if (len(students)==0):
        print("There are no students to display.")
    else:
        print("First Name".ljust(20," ")+"Last Name".ljust(30," ")+"Major".ljust(15," ")+"GPA".ljust(6," "))
        for i in range(len(students)):
            print(students[i]['first'].ljust(20, " "), end="")
            print(students[i]['last'].ljust(30, " "), end="")
            print(students[i]['major'].ljust(15, " "), end="")
            print(str(students[i]['gpa']).ljust(6, " "))
    print("*************************************************************************")

def main():
    keepGoing=True
    menu="""
*************************************************************************
College Roster System
*************************************************************************
Main Menu:
a) Enter a new Student
b) View all Students
c) Clear Students List
d) Exit
*************************************************************************
Choose an option: """
    while keepGoing:
        choice=input(menu)
        if choice!="":
            if choice.lower()=="a":
                addStudent()
            elif choice.lower()=="b":
                displayStudents()
            elif choice.lower()=="c":
                students.clear()
                print("\nThe list of students is cleared.")
            elif choice.lower()=="d":
                keepGoing=False
            else:
                print("\nThat is not a valid selection. Please try again.\n")
        else:
            print("\nYour selection cannot be empty. Please try again.\n")
    print("\nOkay, goodbye!!!")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Most of the errors were basic typos.  For the first error on line 3, I think it's best to use a standard Python `list` to store the data for each student.  A list is created using `[]`.